# py2neo: cannot create graph

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I wanted to experiment with py2neo, but cannot even use the code samples from the documentation. See [here](https://py2neo.org/v4/database.html#py2neo.database.Transaction.create) for example. The code is:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship
g = Graph()
tx = g.begin()
a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
tx.create(a)
b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)
tx.create(ab)
tx.commit()
g.exists(ab)
```

which returns a few error messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\test_py2neo.py", line 22, in <module>
    tx = g.begin()
  File "C:\Users\saran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py", line 335, in begin
    return Transaction(self, autocommit)
  File "C:\Users\saran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\py2neo\database.py", line 797, in __init__
    self.transaction = self.session.begin_transaction()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'begin_transaction'
Exception ignored in: <bound method Driver.__del__ of <neo4j.v1.api.Driver object at 0x000001325C9F0940>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\saran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\api.py", line 151, in __del__
  File "C:\Users\saran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\api.py", line 193, in close
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'close'
```

If I understand well, the API has changed and the documentation has not been updated. But I am using version 4 and the manual seems to be written for that version. Any pointers that could help me get started?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, my bad, I was using py2neo the wrong way. Here is a piece of code that works for me:

```
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
user = "neo4j"
password = "..."

g = Graph(uri=uri, user=user, password=password)

# optionally clear the graph
# g.delete_all()

print(len(g.nodes))
print(len(g.relationships))

# begin a transaction
tx = g.begin()

# define some nodes and relationships
a = Node("Person", name="Alice")
b = Node("Person", name="Bob")
ab = Relationship(a, "KNOWS", b)

# create the nodes and relationships
tx.create(a)
tx.create(b)
tx.create(ab)

# commit the transaction
tx.commit()

print(g.exists(ab))
print(len(g.nodes))
print(len(g.relationships))
```

Obviously, the Neo4j server must be up and running before executing this code.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I am wondering, if I just want to create a node, do I need to begin a transaction and commit it? Or can I just create a node? Because trying [this](https://py2neo.org/2.0/intro.html) example in "Nodes and Relationships" (the basic example), it would not let me. I needed to do it with transaction like you!

Comment: @M.K: Actually, that works too! 

from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship

uri = "bolt://localhost:7687"
user = "..."
password = "..."

g = Graph(uri=uri, user=user, password=password)

alice = Node("Person", name="Alice")
bob = Node("Person", name="Bob")
alice_knows_bob = Relationship(alice, "KNOWS", bob)
g.create(alice_knows_bob)